# Declare variable from another variable in thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

How declare a variable using another variable in thymeleaf?
This is what I want to do:

```
<div th:with="var1='blablabla'">
    <div th:with="var2=${${var1} == null ? '' : 's'}">
       <span th:utext="${tmpCustomerType}">show var2</span>      
    </div>
</div>
```

but the compilator doesn't like that `${var1}`:

> EL1041E:(pos 1): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
>   (org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "${ccc} == null ? '' : ${ccc}" (custom:24))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bad el expression.
Maybe these.

```html
<div th:with="var1='blablabla'">
    <div th:with="var2=var1 == null? '' : 's'">
       <span th:utext="${tmpCustomerType}">show var2</span>      
    </div>
</div>
```